# How to show android app price in user's local currency in my app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-alertdialog

The idea is I wanna show 'buy this app'  with minimum price set for the country user lives in,  in their local currency, in my app as well as in an AlertDialog users will get after some time. Is there some java code that can be used to show local currency in my app and in the AlertDialog?

If it's not possible then can someone guide me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: java cannot convert currencies, as the exchange rate is not constant. You have to get the exchange rate from some API. Also even currency is not a constant for the country, so you have to query a currency from some API as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Currency;
```

import java.util.Locale;

public class CurrencyTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
    displayCurrencyInfoForLocale(defaultLocale);

    Locale swedishLocale = new Locale("sv", "SE");
    displayCurrencyInfoForLocale(swedishLocale);
}

public static void displayCurrencyInfoForLocale(Locale locale) {
    System.out.println("Locale: " + locale.getDisplayName());
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
    System.out.println("Currency Code: " + currency.getCurrencyCode());
    System.out.println("Symbol: " + currency.getSymbol());
    System.out.println("Default Fraction Digits: " + currency.getDefaultFractionDigits());
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Comment: Got the context, but could you please elaborate it cause I don't like to copy and paste?